# code didn't works in loop mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

i have this code, that works without any problem:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".block1").click(function () {
                $("#fade1").fadeIn("slow").fadeOut("slow");
            });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".block2").click(function () {
                $("#fade2").fadeIn("slow").fadeOut("slow");
            });
    });
</script>
```

However, as i have six blocks i am trying change it to a loop:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     for (i=1; i<7; i++) {
         alert(i);
         $(".block"+i).click(function () {
             $("#fade"+i).fadeIn("slow").fadeOut("slow");
             alert (i);
         });
     }
});
```

This for loop isn't working as expected. It's giving all 6 blocks an alert, as expected, but instead of each alert reading "block1", "block2", "block3", etc., they all say "block7".

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a shared class to your divs, you could do it without a loop.

Update:

Its not 100% clear what you are trying to do, but here's a method that could work using [jquery data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/).

```
<div class="animate-block" data-fadeid="fade1"></div>
<div class="animate-block" data-fadeid="fade2"></div>
<div class="animate-block" data-fadeid="fade3"></div>
<div class="animate-block" data-fadeid="fade4"></div>

<div id="fade1"></div>
<div id="fade2"></div>
<div id="fade3"></div>
<div id="fade4"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".animate-block").click(function () {
            var fadeId = $(this).data("fadeid");
            $("#"+fadeId).fadeIn("slow").fadeOut("slow");
        });
});
</script>
```

If your block divs and fade divs are next to each other, it becomes even simpler since you can use the [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method.

```
<div class="animate-block"></div>
<div id="fade1"></div>
<div class="animate-block"></div>
<div id="fade2"></div>
<div class="animate-block"></div>
<div id="fade3"></div>
<div class="animate-block"></div>
<div id="fade4"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".animate-block").click(function () {
            $(this).next().fadeIn("slow").fadeOut("slow");
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer his question. He wants each alert to have a different message - "1" to "6".

Comment: That always fades in `#fade1` every time, not `"#fade" + i`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a closure to capture the current value of `i` so that when `i` is incremented it does not affect previous calls.  Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/UD5sf/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
        alert(i);
        $(".block" + i).click(doIt(i));
    }

    function doIt(i){
        return function(){
            alert(i);
        }
    }
});
```

PS: Feel free to yell at me if I used the term `closure` wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assigning a different class name to each element and appending a number to find the one you're looking for, just assign the same class name to all of them:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".block").click(function(){
        $(this).children(".fade").fadeIn("slow").fadeOut("slow"); 
        alert($(".block").index(this)); //gets the block index
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> but when i press the button give me always 7 in alert.

I'm not exactly sure what you mean here, but do you mean that the second alert always displays "7"?  If so, that is because your `onclick` functions have captured the variable `i`.  You are not capturing a *copy* of `i` but instead each function is capturing a *reference* to it.  So, by the time you press the button, it has a value of `7`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because "i" is a variable that lasts after you've set up all the .click functions. That means that after your loop completes, i has a value of 7. When you click a block and activate it's alert function, the alert is using value of i at that moment in time, which is always 7, because the loop has already finished running.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your click function is using the global value of `i` (7) rather than a static value from the time that you attach the function.

You want to bind the then-current value of i to the click function. There are several ways to do this. Easiest is to make a static function. Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  for (var i=1; i<7; i++) {
    alert(i);
    var click_func = new Function(
      "$('#fade" + i + "').fadeIn('slow').fadeOut('slow');
       alert(" + i + ");");

    $(“.block”+i).click(click_func);
  }
});
```

Comment: Isn't `new Function(` basically just `eval` and not a great idea?

Comment: It's more limited than eval since only a function body can be created. Since the OP wanted to have the concept of meta-programming in a loop, I feel that it is the most straight-forward solution. Alternatives include: 1) creating a closure to maintain a copy of  i as you and Rob W demoed. or 2) Add a property i to the function's object.

Answer (score 0):

That's because by the time your event runs, the loop has finished, and they all use the last value in i, not the value it was when you registered the event.

It should work for the selector,

```
$(".block"+i).click(function ()
```

That should be generating "block1", "block2", etc., and assigning the event.

```
$("#fade"+i).fadeIn("slow").fadeOut("slow");
alert (i);
```

these lines though, they all use `i`, and `i` stays alive as a clojure, and i is assigned 1 to 7, and by the time your event runs, i = 7, so everytime you click ".block1", etc, it will only fade out #fade7 and put alert(7).

Try it like :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (i=1; i<7; i++) {
        alert(i);
        (function (i) {
            $(".block"+i).click(function () {
                $("#fade"+i).fadeIn("slow").fadeOut("slow");
                alert (i);
            });
        })();
    }
});
```